# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Video Production Stack Exchange](http://video.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://video.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Footprint or breadcrumb animation](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14592/footprint-or-breadcrumb-animation)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Canon T3i with Blackmagic Design Intensity to record plays?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13338/canon-t3i-with-blackmagic-design-intensity-to-record-plays)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there a way to directly save DNG Sequences to 16bit exr Sequences in Photoshop or After Effects?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13456/is-there-a-way-to-directly-save-dng-sequences-to-16bit-exr-sequences-in-photosho)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can I multiply 3D cards in a Nuke 3d scene on top of each other, like i can multiply layers in After Effects?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13457/can-i-multiply-3d-cards-in-a-nuke-3d-scene-on-top-of-each-other-like-i-can-mult)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do I build a circle which serves as a particle attracter using After Effects Trapcode Particular?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14566/how-do-i-build-a-circle-which-serves-as-a-particle-attracter-using-after-effects)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do I add an effect on certain length of the original clip in Premiere Pro CS6 using Keyframes?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13346/how-do-i-add-an-effect-on-certain-length-of-the-original-clip-in-premiere-pro-cs)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the name of this type of treatment in video/audio?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13364/what-is-the-name-of-this-type-of-treatment-in-video-audio)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Remove audio from video annotation in ActivePresenter](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14554/remove-audio-from-video-annotation-in-activepresenter)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to create light wall of letters?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13367/how-to-create-light-wall-of-letters)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How is laserdisc information physically stored on the disc?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14543/how-is-laserdisc-information-physically-stored-on-the-disc)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Answer (score 2):

What do people think about using DuckDuckGo instead of google? I get pretty similar results on both engines, I'm just a bit allergic to google.

Answer (score 0):

LOL, that is so funny.

DuckDuckGo.

First thought, someone is pulling my leg.

Second thought, Howard the Duck starts a search engine company :)

I like it :D
nice find.

Comment: DDG is big amongst us crazy tinfoil-hat-types, who are a bit uncomfortable with the idea of everything we search for and every email we receive being spied on for commercial gain.

Answer (score 0):

### It's a Branding/Positioning Issue

Because the consumer market utilizes Google more I believe indexing there, staying familiar with it and prioritizing it is more important than individual preference. People "Google" their problems, they don't "DuckDuckGo" them...

I think the lack of awareness that this site is a great place to get your problem solved is more a marketing problem than anything else.

Then there is the problem of how "forums" like this work. People are condensing and Reddit is now the goto for those who remember and like forums. In terms of having problems solved its now about indexing in Google, Finding a reddit forum or a YouTube Video or a Google Hangout or a Facebook Group. Platforms are now becoming the things. And aside from that it it's Influencers. Top and Bottom, no middle.

So the question becomes can StackExchange become a platform of choice or brand itself as a site with experts/influencers participating?

I went the influencer route with my own personal brand rather than the "Company" legitimacy route and it has paid off. 25K subs in YouTube with most of that being in the last 12 months. So I'd say that shifting in one of those directions and marketing that way is the answer...